# Best practice for realizing tasks with the need of very comprehensive SQL-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

For a task in a managerial accounting context, I generated a relatively large SQL-Query with a MySQL-DB. This query has close to 600 lines and generates as a result a large table with the economic analysis for different products.

This works fine so far and the query just takes about 3 seconds.

But the outcome is only the analysis for one month. Now we would like to execute the query for a couple of month and aggregate the results.

I simply could change the query to include a larger time period as a condition (now just one month). But that would lead to an incorrect (averaged) distribution of overhead costs due to ignoring of larger monthly fluctuations in certain key figures.

Therefore, I think, I would have to generate one (sub-)table per month I would like to analyze. Finally, all these sub-tables would have to be aggregated with a superordinate main query. That should probably work, but this query would then be really large. E.g. for 12 months I would need about 12 x 600 lines for the sub-queries and about another 100 lines for the main query.

This leads to my question: Is this the way how one would do that? Without better knowing, it seems to me an unusually large query which also might be cumbersome to maintain. What would be the best practice way to accomplish the given task?

Thank you

Comment: What does a result row represent? A product? I.e. you get one row per product, say, `product_id, product_name, sum(purchased), sum(sold), sum(vat), min(price), avg(price), etc.`?

Comment: How about creating a View that can be queried to return the results for a single month and then a `select monthly_view.* from monthly_view where month = x UNION select monthly_view.* from monthly_view where month = y UNION ...`

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner

Exactly, one row represents a product. And the columns are medium-detailed cost and revenue figures. First, revenues, then direkt costs and further below certain overhead costs which are distributed among all products in dependence of certain distribution factors. The bottom-line (the last column) is the full-cost P&L for a single product.

Comment: @neurotic-d: Thank you for your answer (and sorry for the late response). That could work. I'll have a look into that and give feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is static once the month is over you can launch your select at the beginning of each month (to calculate the previous month) and store the result in a table with an extra column "month".

```
insert into monthly_aggregation (month, ...)
select ... <600 lines of SQL for specific month>
```

This can be triggered at the beginning of every month.

If historical data can change, you have to rebuild the whole table by executing the INSERT-SElECT per month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and sorry for the late response). That could work. I'll try that out and give feedback...

Comment: Awesome, that works. I just have to add the month to the select part of the query (e.g. insert into monthly_aggregation (month, ...all other columns) select 1 month, 600 lines of  query (except the first select).
Many thx!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your query showing products for a particular month:

```
select product_id, sum(purchased), avg(price), ...
from <many tables>
where month = 6
group by product_id;
```

Then you can change it thus to have it show product data per month:

```
select month, product_id, sum(purchased), avg(price), ...
from <many tables>
group by month, product_id;
```

You can then work on this with an outer query:

```
select ...
from
(
  select month, product_id, sum(purchased), avg(price), ...
  from <many tables>
  group by product_id, month
) product_and_month
group by ...;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and sorry for the late response). I see that your answer would work in general. Nevertheless (and admittingly one could not see that from my problem description) the query is a bit more complicated, e.g. different subqueries use different time period markers (e.g. 04-2016; m4; (m4+m3+m2+m1+ly) - (m3+m2+m1+ly) ) due to different data sources and calculation needs. Therefore, I am not sure how to implement your suggestion into my query. But thanks again